# Rails "respond_to" in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Lately I have been trying out Rails, and I came to love the respond_to.

Is it possible to do something like this in PHP?, responding to different types of requests. So it is easy to implement an alternate way even if javascript is disabled.

Comment: Is there a particular php framework you are thinking of? Or are you rolling your own?

Comment: Yep!, I'm creating a framework for learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dispatch on the filename suffix as Krule suggests, but I believe Rails determines which content type to choose by examining the value of the HTTP `Accept` header (see [Content negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) on Wikipedia). In pseudo-code

```
$data = fetch_some_data();
switch (get_preferred_response_type($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'])) {
    case 'text/html':
       render_html($data); break;
    case 'application/xml':
       render_xml($data);
    case 'application/json':
       render_json($data);
    // etc...
}
```

The `get_preferred_response_type()` function will have to parse the `Accept` header and return the client's preferred MIME type. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/cobweb/source/browse/trunk/utilities/miscellaneous.inc.php#86) is an example of such a function which should help you get started; otherwise there is a [content negotiation library](http://ptlis.net/source/php-content-negotiation/) for PHP  which does all the dirty work for you.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Last time I did something similar to `respond_to` in Rails I used Apache .htaccess RewriteRule in order to process GET variables to php. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (\d*\.?\d*?).(html|json|xml|txt) /file.php?format=$1
```

I hope it helps at least a bit.
Good luck.

Comment: Nice, at least I have something now. Thanks!